# Use derived class to add properties and maintain compatibility with existing classes

Tags: qt, inheritance, copy-constructor, qt6

I'm writing a Qt 6.2.0 application running in Ubuntu 20.04.
My goal is to add a property to the existing class `QtOpcUaNode`.
So I wrote:

```
class MyOpcUaNode : public QOpcUaNode
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyOpcUaNode(QOpcUaNode *parent = nullptr) : QOpcUaNode(parent) { }
    bool updated;
};
```

But here the first error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘QOpcUaNode::QOpcUaNode(QOpcUaNode*&)’
In file included from ../MyProject/myproject.cpp:1:
../MyProject/myproject.h: In constructor ‘MyOpcUaNode::MyOpcUaNode(QOpcUaNode*)’:
../MyProject/myproject.h:16:73: error: no matching function for call to ‘QOpcUaNode::QOpcUaNode(QOpcUaNode*&)’
   16 |     explicit MyOpcUaNode(QOpcUaNode *parent = nullptr) : QOpcUaNode(parent) { }
      |                                                                         ^
```

I want to use my class in this way:

```
QList<MyOpcUaNode *> _listOpcNodes;

_listOpcNodes.append(MyOpcUaNode(_opcUaClient->node("ns=4;s=MEM_RUN_LINE")));
...
_listOpcNodes[x]->updated = true;
```

Is it correct my approach?

I tried **without** the copy-constructor but I was not sure how to convert a `QOpcUaNode *` to `MyOpcUaNode *`. Trying with:

```
MyOpcUaNode *node = qobject_cast<MyOpcUaNode *>(_opcUaClient->node("ns=4;s=MEM_RUN_LINE"));
```

lead `node` to be a `null` pointer (even if the `_opcUaClient->node` was correct).

Comment: QOpcUaNode has no public ctor so you can't derive from it

Comment: And what do you suggest in order to add a property to it, then? Because I need to flag that an element of the list is updated when the `OpcUaNode::attributeRead` signal is emitted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add property to class which inherits from `QObject`, you can do it with `setProperty()` https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setProperty. Well, it is not type-safe but it is very simple. Sometimes pragmatism beats purism.